How to update specific PHP version on Windows?
Is there a way to update PHP via Terminal (Windows PowerShell) or Git Bash?
Currently, I am on PHP 7.2, but I wanted to update it to 8.2.

How did you install PHP in the first place?

i cant remember exactly, probably it was through xampp installation

If you used XAMPP to install PHP, why not update XAMPP itself?

i want to keep other configurations intact and do a quick PHP upgrade

This is done with chocolatey installed.

Run Windows Powershell with admin rights
Execute choco upgrade php --version=8.2
Check current php version after installation with php -v

If still on old version:

Run windows search for "Edit the system environment variables"
Click on "Environment Variables"
Under "System variables", click on "Path" and Edit
Remove the outdated php directory (e.g. C:\xampp\php)
Notice the new php version path that has "php82"
Check php version

If still not updated:

Check php path with which php in git bash (the directory will be C:\xampp\php if it outputs /c/xampp/php/php)
Go to the new php version path and replace folder to the directory (have to rename the new folder to match the original, mine will be renamed from "php82" to "php")
Check php version

